# SSH Connection with keys (no password) follows a One-way traffic?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, private-key

I have a general question about SSH connections. Have already checked some related posts and documents about the matter but could not find a straight answer.

SSH Connection using keys presumes the client has a key pair (public and private) and the server that will have a connection requested has only the pub key.

My question is: as everything depends upon the decryption possible only through the private key, if we try to make the "reverse way" (i.e. the "server" asking connection to the "client") are we supposed to expect a denial?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as everything depends upon the decryption possible only through the private key

It's not decryption. Public-key authentication in SSH uses *signatures* which the other end verifies. (The same is true both for the client verifying the server's hostkeys, and for the server verifying the user's personal authorized_keys.)

While some algorithms (such as RSA) perform signing and decryption in very similar ways and can use the same kind of key for both, this doesn't actually mean they're the same kind of operation.

> if we try to make the "reverse way" (i.e. the "server" asking connection to the "client") are we supposed to expect a denial?

Yes, but not exactly for the reason you mention.

SSH connections made in opposite directions are completely independent from each other. The public key that a client uses for outgoing connections is stored in a different place than the public key that a server uses for verifying incoming ones. (For example, on Linux, clients read public keys from `id_rsa.pub` while servers read them from the `authorized_keys` file.)

That is, even if a system "has" a public key when acting as a client, it still won't automatically "have" the same public key when acting as a server. So in your example, even if you actually copied the private key from the "client" to the "server" and tried to connect in reverse, you'd still get a denial.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If both client and server have the pub key added to the authorized_keys file, would the connection happen (considering my "reverse" example), or we can still expect a denial?